# Open different page as defined when calling notify function in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

In my code, I wish to be able to call the function notify each time with a different link, and the specific notification created opens a new tab with that page when clicked
Note: I'm very confused by the documentation, please don't just link me to that, I really want an explanation with an example. Thanks

This is what I have so far:

```
function notify(title, msg, link, callback) {
    //no idea what to do with the link here
    var options = {
        title: title,
        message: msg,
        type: "basic", 
        iconUrl: "Icon.png" 
    };
    return chrome.notifications.create("", options, callback);
}
```

And to call the function:

`notify("title", "message", "http://www.example.com", function(notification) { });`

which would display

Title
Message

and upon clicking, would open a new tab to http://www.example.com

then later, I would call it again with 
`notify("title", "message", "http://www.google.com", function(notification) { });`

and that one would open a new tab to http://www.google.com when clicked

Thanks if you can help!

Comment: I'm really confused by it, though yes, I have

Comment: Can you please help? Thanks

Comment: I am writing an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct support for attaching an `onclick` handler to a notification. Instead, if you click a notification's body, it will generate a general [`chrome.notification.onClicked`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications#event-onClicked) event, providing the ID of the notification.

You will have, therefore, to maintain your own matching of IDs to URLs.

```
var urls = {};

chrome.notifications.onClicked.addListener(notifyClick);
chrome.notifications.onClosed.addListener(notifyClose);

function notify(title, msg, link, callback) {
  var options = {
    title: title,
    message: msg,
    type: "basic", 
    iconUrl: "Icon.png",
    isClickable: true // New in Chrome 32, alters the appearance?
  };
  return chrome.notifications.create("", options, function(id) {
    // New ID will be generated
    urls[id] = link;
  });
}

function notifyClick(id) {
  // Look up the URL:
  chrome.tabs.create({url: urls[id]});
  // Optionally, close the notification:
  // chrome.notifications.clear(id, function(){});
}

function notifyClose(id, byUser) {
  // Clean up the matching
  delete urls[id];
}
```

Please note: there is a caveat regarding closing notification programmatically. If the notification is closed from the message center, [it will not immediately disappear](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=335918).